# Django: Accessing Non-Unique Fields

Tags: django, django-models, orm, foreign-keys, relational-database

I apologize. I am also surprised I can't find this question asked already. Embarrassment in 3, 2, 1...

**How do I access another model's non-unique field?**

Let us say we have 2 people and a pet, simplified to instantiated JSON examples:

```
Person 1: {
  id: 1,
  first_name: "John",
  last_name: "Doe"
}

Person 2: {
  id: 2,
  first_name: "Jane"
  last_name: "Doe"
}

Pet: {
  id: 1,
  name: "Guess",
  owner_first_name: "{I want person 1's, first_name string value here}",
  owner_last_name: "{I want person 1's, last_name string value here}"
}
```

I get that an object requires a unique primary key, most frequently "id", but there's got to be a way to access secondary fields after using a functional PK.
I know the models.to_field would currently work to access first name, if it's set to unique=True. Eventually, there will be another "John" or "Jane", and there's already 2 "Doe"s here.

**Forgive the syntax butchery for simplification, but how do I get this in Django?**

**Pet.owner_first_name = Person[id].first_name(unique=False)**

Answer (score 0):

If you have defined your relationships in your models correctly (with a field in `Pet` referring to the owner `Person` by way of a `ForeignKey`), you can do this:

```
pet = Pet.objects.get(pk=1)
print(pet.owner.first_name, pet.owner.last_name)
```

In other words, when relating one model to another, you save in the referring model (and the corresponding database table) a reference to the primary key of the referred model instead of specific attributes like first or last name.

The [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/) offer a wealth of examples on the use of various types of relationships; the relevant type for your example being [many-to-one relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/).